# Exibição da pesquisa no wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Fala amigos,

Gostaria de saber se tem algum modo de exibir a pesquisa feita em um site wordpress dessa forma:

**Post** = no formato "x", e, **Página** = no formato "y"

valeu!

Comment: Ficou meio confusa sua pergunta, consegue explicar um pouco melhor?

Comment: @DanielCosta man, assim.. Fiz uma pesquisa... a exibição é padrão para páginas e posts.
Eu quero que quando aparecer uma página do WP, apareça em retângulo. E quando for post quero que apareça em quadrado...

Ai exemplo, pesquisei sobre "Arroz"... Tenho 2 páginas que falam sobre o arroz e 3 posts que tbm falam sobre o arroz...

A exibição que eu quero é a seguinte... 

Arroz - Retângulo, Arroz - Retângulo, Arroz - Quadrado, Arroz - Quadrado, Arroz - Quadrado.

Não sei se da para fazer isso com um simples "if"... 
If(página){ Exibição Retângulo}
else if(post){ Exibição Quadrada}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No arquivo search.php do seu tema no WordPress, você pode utilizar o método **get_post_type();** para verificar o tipo de conteúdo do post.

Exemplo:

```
<?php
get_header();
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        //verifica se é post ou página
        if (get_post_type() == "page") {
            //exibe título da página em um retangulo
            echo "<div class='retangulo'>";
            the_title();
            echo "</div>";
        }
        else if (get_post_type() == "post") {
            //exibe título do post em um quadrado
            echo "<div class='quadrado'>";
            the_title();
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Vlw amigo! É mais simples do que eu imaginava.